# Examples of prime ideals?

Tags: factoring

Could anyone provide me with very simple examples of prime ideals (that is,principle ideals in the ring of integers which are generated by a prime), explaining me the way they are generated? The public audience is made up of high schoold people, abour 17 years of age......

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prime ideals in $\Bbb Z$ are quite simple, just $p\Bbb Z$ for prime $p$ (and $0$), so although they make a good motivator for the naming sense they don't (IMO) show why the definition is necessary in more generality. Perhaps prime ideals in a polynomial ring might give a better sense of the purpose of the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prime ideals in the integers are exactly the ideals generated by a single element. For example, you might take $(2) = 2\mathbb{Z} = \{ 2z \mid z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ or $(3) = 3\mathbb{Z} = \{ 3z \mid z \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Replace 2 or 3 with any prime $p$ and arrive at a similar notion.

To be more explicative, take $(7)$. This is the set of all integer multiples of 7, i.e. $\{\cdots,-14,-7,0,7,14,21,\cdots\}$. The reason this is an ideal is because if you take any integer and multiply it by an element of this list, you will get another element of the list, sometimes said it **absorbs** the ring of integers.

As per a comment, an ideal $P$ is called **prime** when given any two ring elements, say $r$ and $s$, if $rs \in P$, then either $r \in P$ or $s \in P$. For instance, if $a \cdot b = 7 \cdot c$ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}$, either $7 \mid a$ or $7\mid b$, right? How else would 7 be a factor of the product?

Prime ideals are nice because you can use them to split up quotient rings by an ideal via the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Letting your ring be $R$, if $I = \prod_{j=1}^k I_j^{e_j}$ and $I_j$ are ideals and pairwise coprime (for any $m$ and $n$, $I_m + I_n = R$), with $e_j$ as positive integers, then $R/I \simeq \prod_{j=1}^k R/(I_j)^{e_j}$. That is to say, you can split up the quotient ring into quotient by these smaller ideals. For instance, taking $\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$, we know $30\mathbb{Z} = 2\mathbb{Z}\times 3\mathbb{Z} \times 5\mathbb{Z}$, and each of these are pairwise coprime, we have that $\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: This answer seems to be more about ideals than prime ideals. Could you explain what the "prime" part means when talking about ideals?

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I edited to include more information about prime ideals in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain in which way those prime ideals you provide allow to recover the unique factorization which had been lost?

Comment: @JavierArias The fundamental theorem of arithmetic (that all natural numbers can be factored as a product of prime numbers) comes down to what's called the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which is a more complicated statement than one you might want to be trying to explain to 17 year old high school students. I can add it to my answer if you like, though.

Comment: @walkar Yes please :)

Comment: It is worth explicit emphasis that CRT does not require distinct *prime* ideals. Rather it, requires only ideals being pairwise *coprime,* i.e. comaximal, i.e.  $\,I_j + I_k = 1\,$ for $\,j\ne k.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque That's right, I forgot the exponents. I'm editing now.